# Legendas Figura

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Gostaria de saber porquê aparece na imagem um marcador na coluna dos 2dB na linha dos 10^0 e como poderei eliminar isso sem o apagar os marcadores que se encontram sobre a linha azul, que é o que pretendo?

O código para fazer o plot é este:

```
#=========================== Gráfico=====================================
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(EbNo_theory, ber_MFSK, 'b-', EbNodB, ber, 'ko')
plt.axis([0, 8, 1e-4, 1e0])
plt.xscale('linear')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('EbNo(dB)')
plt.ylabel('BER')
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('BER sem repetição(Teórico) - FSK Coerente com M=2')
#=======================Legendas==================
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Teórico', color='blue')
line_down, = plt.plot([2,3,1], marker='o', markersize=4, label='Simulado', color='black')
plt.legend(handles=[line_up, line_down])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É só editar a linha: `plt.ylabel('BER')`, ou assim estaria removendo os valores também?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está na sua legenda. 
No seu código você tem:

```
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Teórico', color='blue')
line_down, = plt.plot([2,3,1], marker='o', markersize=4, label='Simulado', color='black')
```

como não foi especificado X e Y, você efetivamente tem os pares (X,Y) em (0,1),(1,2),(2,3) para `line_up` e (0,2),(1,3),(2,1) para `line_down`.

O último ponto (2,1) é plotado com uma marca preta e aparece no seu gráfico no ponto mencionado. Creio que o ponto (0,1) em azul deve aparecer também, mas como é uma linha para cima, não fica tão marcada.

Para resolver você pode declarar a legenda juntamente quando você plota os seu valores e remover a parte atual para legenda ou então use os valores apropriados no gráfico para o seu *dummy plot*, tal qual os abaixo:

```
line_up, = plt.plot([100,100,100],[1,2,3], label='Teórico', color='blue')
line_down, = plt.plot([100,100,100],[2,3,1], marker='o', markersize=4, label='Simulado', color='black')
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu o meu problema